# Exponential of an upper triangular matrix filled with 1.

Tags: lie-groups

I need to find the exponential of the following matrix:

$$
A=
  \begin{pmatrix} 
  1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & \cdots &1 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots &1 \\
    \vdots & \vdots& \vdots& \ddots & \vdots\\
  0&0&0 & \cdots&1 
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

Where $A$ is a square matrix. I have already tried to find a general form for $A^{k}$, I found that again the diagonal is filled with 1, and for example in the case $n=4$ the super diagonal is filled with k, the next diagonal is the $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ and I thought the $A_{14}$ position was going to be something like $\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}$ but it does not work as I expected. I'm trying to do this to find the exponential of a Jordan block and for $A$, I need to get this: 
$$ 
\begin{pmatrix}
 0&e^{\lambda}& \frac{e^{\lambda}}{2!} & \cdots &\frac{e^{\lambda}}{(n-1)!}\\
 0&0&e^{\lambda}&\cdots &\frac{e^{\lambda}}{(n-2)!} \\
 \vdots&\vdots&\vdots& \ddots& \vdots\\
 0&0&0& \cdots &0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm thinking this is going to be a roll up your sleeves kind of induction. Uniqueness of Taylor expansions tells us that the coefficients of $\lambda^n$ have to look like what we expect in each entry, so it should work out. But it probably won't be pleasant.

Comment: That last matrix doesn’t look right. If you’re looking for $e^A$, its diagonal should be filled with $e$, not $0$.

Answer (score 2):

The original matrix $A = I + N,$ where $I$ is the identity matrix, and $N$ is the strictly upper diagonal part. Since $IN = NI,$ we find that
$$ e^{At} = e^{It} e^{N t} = e^t e^{Nt}. $$
You need to go through the details for small dimension, the point is that $N$ is nilpotent. In dimension $2,$ $N^2 = 0.$ In dimension $3,$ $N^3 = 0.$ So you can find $e^N$ and $e^{Nt},$ worth writing out.